# WCF to WPF class how about INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, wcf, inotifypropertychanged

I have the following WCF class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

When I retrieve this class to my WPF application, I want it to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Should I copy the data to a different class once retrieved from WCF, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged or should I implement it in the WCF class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to add a reference using Add Service reference in Visual Studio- by default this creates a Reference.svcmap file that has the following element     `<EnableDataBinding>true</EnableDataBinding>`. This element controls the generation of code for INotifyPropertyChanged. By default this is set to true so the client classes that get generated will already implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

If you are using the command tool (svcutil.exe), you will want to look into the option /enableDataBinding- [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your `Book` class. As long as this same `Book` class is available for both your WCF service implementation and WPF application, you should be fine.